# Alinhamento vertical CSS baseado na altura de outro elemento

Tags: css

estou a tentar criar um bloco que contém uma imagem com conteúdo ao lado, onde pretendo que a imagem esteja alinhada ao centro baseado na altura do conteúdo. Deixo aqui um esquema daquilo que pretendo. Já tentei alinhamentos transformando o container em table mas não consigo obter aquilo que pretendo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tendo em conta que o tamanho da imagem é conhecido, usando posicionamento absoluto na imagem e margens negativas:

exemplo: http://codepen.io/cmpscabral/pen/wadaqX

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    background:#eee;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 450px;

    img {
      position:absolute;
      left:0;
      top:50%;
      margin-top:-100px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sugiro aplicar flex na div pai, mas não suporta browsers antigos...
Entretanto se você colocar parte do CSS dá pra saber melhor se há outras saídas para o e problema.

`display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 flex-direction: row;
 justify-content: space-around;`

Fonte: [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

OBS. Não ficou muito claro pra mim se o resultado que você deseja é a primeira ou a segunda imagem, se for a segunda imagem talvez minha sugestão ajude...